# Am I doing right for hashing function?

Tags: c, hash

I am assigned to do following :

> The easiest hashing function it to read the string a character by
>   character and consider each character as an unsigned 8-bit number
>   between 0 and 255. Then we add all the characters modulo some integer 
>   k resulting in an integer between 0 and k-1. We assume the previous
>   hashing function. The hashing function adds the bytes of a string
>   modulo k. The size of the hash table is k.

Thus, I coded like following:

```
unsigned hash (char *s)
{
 unsigned hashval;

 for (hashval = 0; *s != '\0'; s++) { 
    hashval += *s;    
}

 return hashval % HASHSIZE;
}
```

Here, HASHSIZE is equivalent to K in specification.

But I am not sure if I am doing correctly, Is this really hash function?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I am not sure if I am doing correctly, Is this really hash function?

I take you to be asking whether your code accurately implements the specification you provided.  It does not, at least not in a portable manner, though it's close.  The main issue is its failure to address this provision of the specification:

> > consider each character as an unsigned 8-bit number

C allows the `char` type to be either signed or unsigned, at the discretion of the implementation.  Signed `char` is pretty common, and your code does not account for that.

Additionally, although C requires `char` to be the same size as `unsigned char`, and it requires `unsigned char` to have *at least* 8 bits, none of them padding bits, it does not require *exactly* 8 bits.  In practice, however, all modern systems use 8-bit `char`s, and it seems unlikely that the exercise expects you to account for the possibility of larger ones.

***To address this issue,*** you need to convert each `char` in the string to an unsigned 8-bit number before adding it to the accumulator variable.  There are several ways to do that.  If you are willing to assume that `unsigned char` has exactly 8 bits, then the easiest thing to do is just to cast each character to that type before adding.

---

As a secondary issue, your function does not necessarily implement the modular addition as described in the spec:

> > The hashing function adds the bytes of a string modulo k.

The risk here is that the sum of all the characters in the string is enough to overflow type `unsigned`.  The maximum value of that type can be as small as 65535 (though in most modern implementations it's much larger), and at that size, it is plausible that the sum of the input string's characters would overflow.  In that case, waiting until the end to compute the remainder will produce the wrong result unless parameter *K* is a power of 2.

Note also that choosing type `unsigned int` for the result limits the allowable *K* to be at most `UINT_MAX + 1`, and using `unsigned int` for the internal accumulator variable is inconsistent with values of *K* between `UINT_MAX - 254` and `UINT_MAX` (but `UINT_MAX + 1` is still ok).

***To (mostly) address this issue,*** compute and store the modulus after adding each character, instead of waiting until the end to do so.

If you need to accommodate *K* close to but less than `UINT_MAX + 1`, then you'll need also to watch out for the addition overflowing, and to apply a correction in the event that overflow occurs.